# Calling a Scala program from command line

Tags: scala, command-line

I know it seems like a beginner question and that there are quite a lot of *related* questions, but I believe mine is a bit specific and I did not find the answer.

My arborescence is the following :

```
root
   jsoup-1.8.2.jar
   bin
      miscellaneous
         md2html.class
```

The `bin` directory is the generated by Eclipse and I don't take care of the compilation. All the following commands are executed from `bin`. At first, I forgot to include Jsoup in the classpath :

`scala miscellaneous.markdown.md2html C:\Users\Dici\Desktop\fancy-examples\test\test.md --theme amazon`

It logically resulted in the following error : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/nodes/Document`, but I was still able to run `md2html` by commenting the Jsoup-related code.

Then, I added it to the classpath :

`scala -classpath "..\jsoup-1.8.2.jar" miscellaneous.markdown.md2html C:\Users\Dici\Desktop\fancy-examples\test\test.md --theme apple`

I would expect this to work, but it doesn't :

```
No such file or class on classpath: miscellaneous.markdown.md2html
```

Why adding something to the classpath breaks a valid command ?

Comment: Any reason for downvoting me ? I think my question is clear and well presented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the classpath, you removed the current directory which is where the md2html.class file is located.

```
scala -classpath "..\jsoup-1.8.2.jar:.:" miscellaneous.markdown.md2html
     C:\Users\Dici\Desktop\fancy-examples\test\test.md --theme apple
```

The classpath seperator for windows is `;` and linux is `:`. The `.` is shorthand for the current directory. It might be better to give an absolute path to the class file, but I am thinking you need more than one class. The `.` will include all class files in that directory.

Comment: Tried it, did not work. Note that the current directory is not where md2html is located, since I execute the commande from bin